# Rank numbers in a loop vb.net

Tags: vb.net, loops, while-loop, numbers

I currently pull data from a database and rank them when i loop through them. Example of such numbers are `45, 45, 67, 99, 34, 65, 88, 22, 90, 90, 90, 23, 55, 46`. These are a total of 14 numbers, I want to loop through and assign rank.

```
 Dim i As Integer() = {45, 45, 67, 99, 34, 65, 88, 22, 90, 90, 90, 23, 55, 46}
    Dim lastScore As Integer
    Dim position As Integer = 0

    For Each i1 In i
        If Val(lastScore) <> Val(i1) Then
            position += 1
            Console.WriteLine(position & vbCrLf)
        ElseIf Val(lastScore) = Val(i1) Then
            Console.WriteLine(position & vbCrLf)
            position += 1
        End If
        lastScore = Val(i1)
    Next
```

The current output of the code above is:

```
1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14
```

Which is wrong. The expected output is supposed to be:

```
1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 12, 13, 14
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you use a database that supports ranking functions you should do it there

Comment: Probably you shouldn't increase the `position` in case `Val(lastScore) = Val(i1)`. Also, your else branch doesn't have to be an `ElseIf`, a regular `Else` would do the trick (no need to re-evaluate the exact opposite of your initial `if` statement)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I want to be able to rank it myself using a loop

Comment: @Icepickle If the `Position` is not increased in case of `Val(lastScore) = Val(i1)`, it is still not correct.

Comment: Your approach also relies on the order. So you wouldn't get the same "ranks" if it wasn't ordered.

Comment: @BlackPearl So, You are arbitrarily deciding that you shouldn't have rank 2 in your expected output, however, when you have 3 '9' your output should be 12 instead of 11? I'm not sure how you want your rank calculated there

Comment: Your ranking is not at all clear so I am struggling to understand a solution. Your code does not compile with option strict on either as you are treating a string like and integer. Also you don't need any of those `Val`'s

Comment: @TimSchmelter the figures will be ordered like the example. I mean the numbers that occur more than once will be close to each other.

Comment: @MattWilko The data type is not the problem here, the example is just lifted from somewhere.

Comment: @Icepickle typo, sorry. It is like so `1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 12, 13, 14`

Comment: Then the answer from Tamás should do, I would say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an ugly code which creates the expected output:

```
    Dim i As Integer() = {45, 45, 67, 99, 34, 65, 88, 22, 90, 90, 90, 23, 55, 46}
    Dim lastScore As Integer
    Dim lastScorePosition As Integer
    Dim position As Integer = 1

    For Each i1 In i
        If Val(lastScore) <> Val(i1) Then
            Console.Write(position & ",")
            lastScorePosition = position
            lastScore = Val(i1)
        Else
            Console.Write(lastScorePosition & ",")
        End If
        position += 1
    Next
```

Comment: Any chance you could explain better, why you find it an ugly code, and what he could do to improve his code? Also, do you really need the `Val` expressions still?

Comment: @Icepickle the code was imported, the `Val()` is necessary in the subroutine from which it was imported from.

Comment: @lcepickle Why ugly?e.g. no variable initialization therefore the code fails when the array starts with 0.

Comment: True, just it's easier if such a statement is also explained for people who want to use your code afterwards, so that they don't have to find out these things

Answer (score 0):

The expected result is not correct. I.e. why there is not rank 2?

Simple ranking is achieved with relatively simple code:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim i As Integer() = {45, 45, 67, 99, 34, 65, 88, 22, 90, 90, 90, 23, 55, 46}
    Dim lastScore As Integer
    Dim position As Integer

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder

    For Each i1 In i
        If Not lastScore = i1 Then position += 1
        sb.Append(position & ", ")
        lastScore = i1
    Next

    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 2, 2)
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString)

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

The output is:

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11
```